# How to stop navigation in useMutation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, spring, tailwind-css

I have a signup form and I am using `useMutation` to post the request to the database on successful login I want to show a snackbar and then navigate to other pages, but in my case, it is not happening it immediately navigates to other pages with showing snackbar, I want it to show and the navigate.

```
useMutation({
  mutationFn: fnname,
  onSuccess: () => {
    setOpen(true)
    navigate('/somepath')
  },
})
```

This setOpen is for React material sanckbar

Comment: Javascript != Java

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want? 
Just by this snippet it is hard to understand, also do you mean "without showing"?
Top of my head with this bit info you provided either use a modal, have the snackbar wrapper passed down via props or use context.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.